# I have one table containing some fields like Firstname,company name etc

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have one table containing some fields like Firstname,companyname etc.. Now I want the Companyname whose First Character is starting from "A" and if Company name is empty then search condition will be applied on First name i.e First Character starts from "A".how can i solve it? Give me query for that. I have applied query like :

var query = _affiliateRepository.Table;
            if (!showHidden)
                query = query.Where(a => a.Active);

```
        if (Where(from a in query where a.Address.Company.HasValue))
            query = from a in query where a.Address.FirstName.StartsWith("a") select a;
        else
            query = from a in query where a.Address.Company.StartsWith("a") select a;
        query = from a in query where a.Address.Company.StartsWith("a") select a;
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://WhatHaveYouTried.com)

Comment: Showing what you've tried and why it didn't work as you expected would raise your chances to get an answer. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think you need the LINQ equivalent of a COALESCE in SQL. For each row you need to look at both the Company Name and the FirstName to determine which to do the comparison against.

Something like this may work:

.Select (c => (c.Company ?? c.FirstName))
   .Where (c => c.StartsWith ("A"))

Comment: Thanks but I company name need more preference for starting from "A". I have to check for First name only and only in situation where company name is empty. Can you help me to do so?

Comment: I am not clear what you mean, can you post a little example data with what you expect?